# How to get the main text of an element by DOMDocument

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I want to get the main text of an element without the child elements with `DOMDocument`. For example,

```
<span>
This is the main
    <i>more</i>
    <b>extra</b>
<span>
```

I get the text by

```
$text=$g->query('//span')[0]->nodeValue;
```

but how can I get only the text value, which is under `span`. Here, only `This is the main` text by ignoring any child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`text()` node test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Node_tests):

```
echo $g->query('//span/text()')[0]->nodeValue;
```

Output is:

```
This is the main
```

This will only find text nodes that are direct children of a `<span>`.